# Mongodb aggregate arguments to $lookup must be strings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
        db.absences.insert([
           { "_id" : 1, "student" : "Ann Aardvark", sickdays: [ new Date ("2018-05-01"),new Date ("2018-08-23") ] },
           { "_id" : 2, "student" : "Zoe Zebra", sickdays: [ new Date ("2018-02-01"),new Date ("2018-05-23") ] },
        ])

    db.holidays.insert([
       { "_id" : 1, year: 2018, name: "New Years", date: new Date("2018-01-01") },
       { "_id" : 2, year: 2018, name: "Pi Day", date: new Date("2018-03-14") },
       { "_id" : 3, year: 2018, name: "Ice Cream Day", date: new Date("2018-07-15") },
       { "_id" : 4, year: 2017, name: "New Years", date: new Date("2017-01-01") },
       { "_id" : 5, year: 2017, name: "Ice Cream Day", date: new Date("2017-07-16") }
    ])

db.absences.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "holidays",
           pipeline: [
              { $match: { year: 2018 } },
              { $project: { _id: 0, date: { name: "$name", date: "$date" } } },
              { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$date" } }
           ],
           as: "holidays"
         }
    }
])
```

I'm trying to use pipeline in lookup for aggregation query. Having this as same as from the Mongodb documentation, it still gives an error

```
Unable to execute the selected commands

Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 4570: 'arguments to $lookup must be strings, pipeline: [ { $match: { year: 2018.0 } }, { $project: { _id: 0.0, date: { name: "$name", date: "$date" } } }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$date" } } ] is type array' on server localhost:27017. 

The full response is:
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "arguments to $lookup must be strings, pipeline: [ { $match: { year: 2018.0 } }, { $project: { _id: 0.0, date: { name: \"$name\", date: \"$date\" } } }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: \"$date\" } } ] is type array", 
    "code" : NumberInt(4570), 
    "codeName" : "Location4570"
}
```

I'm using mongodb v3.4.

Answer (score 32):

Because you are trying to use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) features (syntax) from **MongoDB v3.6** on **MongoDB v3.4**

The **MongoDB v3.4 [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** syntax:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

The **MongoDB v3.6 [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)** syntax:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
       pipeline: [ <pipeline to execute on the collection to join> ],
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I referred to this documentation and tried it, which I also mentioned in my question. Please try it on your machine. It will give you the same error.

Comment: This tutorial helps to upgrade MongoDB to 3.6: https://optimalbi.com/blog/2018/05/16/upgrading-mongodb-3-4-to-3-6-on-ubuntu-16-04-easy-as-microwave-pie/

Comment: I use MongoDB v4.4 but still I get this error, would you please guide me.

Answer (score -2):

In $lookup you could just join the collectionfirst and doing the match, project and etc later after lookup. And you should have the foreign field that referring to holidays collection.

Like :

```
{
  $lookup:
     {
       from: "holidays",
       localField: "holidaysID", //yourLocalfield, it is local field in absences. you should have it to join 2 collections
       foreignField : "_id", //theforeignfield, it is _id in the holidays
       as: "holidays"
     }
},{ $match: { year: 2018 } },
{ $project: { _id: 0, date: { name: "$name", date: "$date" } } },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$date" } }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It depends on the MongoDB version. Take a look into documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries (-;

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this doesn't solve my problem. $lookup fetches all the documents from holidays whereas I need to get only selected data from a document.